How to allow only one way traffic with wireguard
With wireguard, is it possible to create a tunnel that will only allow traffic in one direction? For example heres the following scenario:
Given PC-s: A, B, C. A should be able to reach (ping, telnet, etc) B and C, B should be able to reach C, but not backwards.
I figured the AllowedIPs will let me do that but I was mistaken, as it needs to be added on both sides, and it will be bidirectional
The current solution I've found is to set up iptables on each PC and defining every rule about every connection, what to drop and what to accept, but I figured there might be a better solution for this.

That's what you have firewalls for - controlling traffic. Iptables is such a firewall.

Wireguard is a mechanism to carry traffic from one place to another securely (as in cannot be easily read or made sense of if intercepted). Network access controls is a firewall issue.
